# create Dialog with custom format on android

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, popup

Is is possible to create a Dialog with custom format? I mean, not a square Dialog but one with a strange format.

Here´s a picture of what i want:
http://s3.postimg.org/ha5g0d437/popup_chat.png

I want it to be a Dialog for my android app, like a popup. Is it possible to give him this strange format ou i have to work with squares?

Comment: you like it to be like bubble chat right??

Comment: bubble? You mean like a popup? If it is a popup, then yes

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a layout design you need for example add image pop up as a background and then add the EditText layout that you need, add your layout with this code..

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater ();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
dialogBuilder.setView (dialogView);

EditText EditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById (R.id.label_field);
editText.setText ("test label");
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show ();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an `xml` file for the dialog layout in your layout folder. say you name it `dialog.xml` and you can add pic and buttons there. then in your main activity java:

```
        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        myDialog .setTitle("My fancy dialog");
        myDialog .setContentView(R.layout.dailog);
        Button meBtn = (Button) dealerDialogDialog.findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        meBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something or just:
                myDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
```

I hope this help you